# How to reference a function from JavaScript class method

Tags: javascript, reference, deep-linking

I use SWFAddress for deep linking my site ([link to SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/)). I like to break code into classes so I have a main structure similar to this:

```
function SomeClass() {
    // This adds the this.handleChange() function to the
    // SWFAddress event listener
    this.initializeSWFA = function() {
        // SWFAddress variable is instantiated in SWFAddress javascript file
        // so I can use it here
        SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE, this.handleChange);
    }

    // SWFAddress is supposed to call this function
    this.handleChange = function(evt) {
    // Some code here
    }

}

// Instantiate the SomeClass
var someVar = new SomeClass();
someVar.initializeSWFA();
```

This line does not work here:

```
SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE, this.handleChange);
```

I tried changing it to:

```
SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE, this.handleChange());
```

or

```
var self = this;
SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE, self.handleChange);
```

And these don't work either.

So how do I reference a JavaScript function from a class in a situation like this?

If the function `handleChange` would be outside of the class I can write the function's name.

---

First, thank you for all the answers. I am still trying to figure how this all works in JavaScript. I am not used to the object oriented model like here in JavaScript.

This is the solution for now. I still can't figure out how to do this nicely in JavaScript, but this solution works. I tried to implement the solution suggested by ehudokai (thank you), however I was not able to make it work.

```
function SomeClass() {
    // This adds the this.handleChange() function to the
    // SWFAddress event listener
    this.initializeSWFA = function() {
        // SWFAddress variable is instantiated in SWFAddress javascript file
        // so I can use it here
        SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE, someFunc);
    }

    // SWFAddress suppose to call this function
    this.handleChange= function(evt) {
    // Some code here
    }

}

// Instantiate the SomeClass
var someVar = new SomeClass();

function someFunc(evt) {
    someVar.handleChange(evt);
}

someVar.initializeSWFA();
```

I don't like this because this involves defining one extra function, so it takes extra space *if* anybody figures out how to add a method to SWFAddress EventListener from a JavaScript object. Please help me out.

Comment: Since your question in the comments to the now deleted answer also got deleted, I extended my old answer with a reply. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your class structure is perfectly valid. However, if your `handleChange()` function uses the `this` keyword, expecting `someVar`, then that is where your problem lies.

This is what happens:

1. `SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE, this.handleChange);` correctly references the handler function within the class. SWFAddress caches that function to some variable `f` until the event is dispatched.
2. When the event is dispatched, SWFAddress calls `f`. While the reference to the function is preserved, the reference to the context, or `this`, is not. Therefore `this` defaults to `window`.

To get around this, you simply need to use an anonymous function that captures the variables within the class scope. You can call the handler with the correct context from within this anonymous function:

```
function SomeClass() {
    this.initializeSWFA = function() {
        // Save a reference to the object here
        var me = this;

        // Wrap handler in anonymous function
        SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE, function (evt) {
            me.handleChange(evt);
        });
    }

    // SWFAddress suppose to call this function
    this.handleChange= function(evt) {
    // Some code here
    }

}
```

##An explanation of `this`, as requested by the OP:##

The `this` keyword can be explained in different ways: take a read of firstly [this article about scope](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/), and then [this article about object-oriented JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html).

I'd like to throw in my quick reasoning too, which you may find helpful. Remember that JavaScript doesn't have "classes" as languages such as Java do. In those languages, a "method" of a class belongs only to that class (or could be inherited). In JavaScript however, there are only objects, and object properties, which can happen to functions. These functions are free agents -- they don't *belong* to one object or another, just like strings or numbers. For example:

```
var a = {
    myMethod: function () {...}
};

var b = {};
b.myMethod = a.myMethod;
```

In this case, which object does `myMethod` belong to? There is no answer; it could be either `a` or `b`. Therefore `a.myMethod` is simply a reference to a function, disassociated from the "context", or parent object. Therefore `this` has no meaning unless it is **called** explicitly using `a.myMethod()` or `b.myMethod()`, and thus defaults to `window` when called in any other way. It is for the same reason that there is no such thing as a `parent` or `super` keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: Do you know of any article which describes this in detail why `this` would default to `window`. I thought that `this.handleChange` when stored to var `f` will be evaluated to a memory location or however Javascript refers to variables, and then when SWFAddress will call `f`, it will call the memory address of `this.handleChange`.

Comment: Thank you. Your updated answer and the articles were very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. I was encountering this problem too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I can't pinpoint your problem, but I would say that it has something to do with your use of `SWFAddress`. The way you're structuring `SomeClass` and its methods is completely valid, contrary to what some other answers here are stating.

**Further clarification to miki's (now deleted) question from another answer, regarding how `this` works:**

There are two cases for how `this` behaves; regular functions and functions invoked with the `new`-operator.

For regular function invokations, `this` refers to the object to the left of the dot (loosely speaking): For example, when writing `someVar.initializeSWFA()`, `this` will refer to `someVar`. When calling a function without the dot, `this` will refer to the global object. A function can be assigned from one object to another and hence `this` will be shifted, like this:

```
var someVar = new SomeClass();
var anotherVar = {};
anotherVar.aNewNameForTheSameFunction = someVar.initializeSWFA;
anotherVar.aNewNameForTheSameFunction(); // Inside of this call to initializeSWFA, "this" will be "anotherVar"
```

Then we also have the case when invoked with the `new`-operator. In that case, `new` will create a new object for you and `this` will refer to that object.

There are also ways to invoke a function with an explicitly set `this`, by using the `call`-function:

```
var someVar = new SomeClass();
var aNumber = 5;
someVar.initializeSWFA.call(aNumber, arg1, arg2, ..., argN);
```

That will call the function initializeSWFA with `aNumber` as `this` and also pass it the parameters `arg1`, `arg2`, etc. Note that `someVar` is taken out of the equation in that case.

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert in Javascript. So you can add `call()` to any function?

Comment: No need to apologize, that's what this site is for :) And yes, you can add `call` to any function. A function in javascript is an object, just like numbers and string and so on. And just like strings have functions like `indexOf`, `concat` and `replace`, functions have functions too :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing to do is to stop thinking of SomeClass as a *class*.

JavaScript doesn't have classes.  It uses prototypical inheritance.  Which I won't go too deeply into here. Essentially, it means you just have objects.  And if you want to create another object like the first one, you use the Object.prototype attribute to do that.

So if you want to do what you're trying to (assuming that SWFAddress works like most JavaScript), do the following.

```
var someVar = {  // (Using object notation)
    initializeSWFA : function(){
        SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.CHANG, this.handleChange);
    },
    handleChange : function(){
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

At this point you can call someVar directly:

```
someVar.initializeSWFA();
```

If instead you want to create an object that you can inherit other objects from try the following.

```
var baseObject = function(){};
baseObject.prototype.handleChange = function(){
    // Your code here
}
baseObject.prototype.initializeSWFA = function(){
    SWFAddress.addEventListener(SWFAddressEvent.CHANGE, this.handleChange);
}

var someVar = new baseObject();
someVar.initializeSWFA();
```

The *new* operator simply creates a new object that inherits the *.prototype* of the object specified.

Comment: How to reference the baseObject in code of the prototype method?

Comment: You can just call baseObject.handleChange or baseObject.initializesSWFA directly.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question?